# How to limit number of digits after decimal point if digit count is not fixed

Tags: java

I can able to find a answer for limiting numbers after decimal. But if my count after decimal is not fixed, then I have to do something for that. I just want to pass the count for limiting numbers after decimal. The count will differ everytime. So in this case what I want to do? Anybody help me to find a better solution.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: *A better solution* compared to which one? Have you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public static String format(Double d, int decimalPlace) {
        String pattern = "0." + String.format("%0" + decimalPlace + "d", 0);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
        return df.format(d);
    }
```

Example

- format(12.345124,1)  -> 12.3
- format(12.345124,2)  -> 12.34
- format(12.345124,3)  -> 12.345
- format(12.345124,4)  -> 12.3451

Comment: Tq this is what I expected..wrks fr me@Vinay Chaudhary